# Visual Studio missing body element

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I've replaced body element with custom control in aspx page. Eg. instead

```
  <%@ Page %>
  <html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>...</body>
  </html>
```

I have

```
  <%@ Page %>
  <html>
  <head>...</head>
  <app:body runat="server">...</app:body>
  </html>
```

Some warnings appeared (like Element 'body' occurs too few times.) and intellisense inside `<app:body>` is confused.

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to consider server control as a body element?

Comment: Any specific reason for custom server side body control? You can use runat server on form element or body element

Comment: Yes. I use control for body to collect pieces of html code from other controls and render it before closing body tag. For example code for help bubbles, which are normally hidden and shows when user clicks on help icon.